# How can I update the data in highcharts for both x axis & y axis?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am a newbie in Highcharts (and javascript in general).

Please have a look at this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Daan1982/7bX7h/1/

Apparently,

```
$('#container').series[0].setData([100,200],true);
```

is not working. I want to change the data for the y axis and also for the x-axis. However, the setData function is not clear to me.

It would be ideal to have a function like this:

```
updatetheChart(x_first, x_second, y_first, y_second) {
    /// Now some code to update the chart
}
```

Then, I can call this function easily from a button for instance. It sounds easy but for me as a newbie, I need help.

If you have another (jQuery based) solution, this would also be fine if you share it with me in a fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this..
make the highchart method to draw chat and call the method with new data as many number of time you need to redraw the chart as the rendering of chart in high chart is fast.

```
function lineChart(div,Chartdata){
$('#'+div).highcharts({
title: {
   text: 'Calibration',
            x: -20 //center
},
xAxis: {....


series: [{
    name: 'Curve',
    data: Chartdata
}]
}
```

and call like

```
lineChart('container',[10,100,20]);
```

where ever you want...

like wise add the category too... and make your own customized methods

hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

## See the official Demo in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/series-setdata/).

You should add `.highcharts()` after `$('#container')`.

That is `$('#container').highcharts().series[0].setData([100,200],true);`

## [Fixed demo Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/timwzw/7bX7h/3/)

## [The official document.](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.setData)